# How to check if a digit is used in a number multiple times

Tags: javascript

Example: We have the number `1122`. I would like to check that if given number contains the digit `1` more than once. In this case, it should return `true`.

I need the code to be flexible, it has to work with any number, like `3340`, `5660`, `4177` etc.

Comment: Take the non-Javascript solutions that you found, translate them, then come to use with any concrete problems that you face that you couldn't debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **@Aspiring Aqib**'s answer, I made a function that actually works properly and in the way I want.

The way it works is:

> Example execution: `multDig('221','2')`

1. Split the `number` *(first argument)* to an array where each element is one digit.
   *Output: `['2','2','1']`*
2. Run a `for` loop, which checks each of the array elements if they match with the `digit` *(second argument)*, and increment the `times` variable if there is a match.
   *Output: `2`*
3. Check inside the for loop if the match was detected already to improve performance on longer numbers like `2211111111111111`
4. Return *`true`* if the number was found more than once, otherwise, return *`false`*.

And finally the code itself:

```
function multDig(number, digit){
    var finalSplit = number.toString().split(''), times = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < finalSplit.length; i++){
        if (finalSplit[i] == digit){
            times++
        }
        if (times > 1){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily *"force"* JS to coerce any numeric value to a string, either by calling the `toString` method, or concatenating:

```
var someNum = 1122;
var oneCount = (someNum + '').split('1').length;
```

by concatenating a number to an empty string, the variable is coerced to a string, so you can use all the string methods you like (`.match`, `.substring`, `.indexOf`, ...). 
In this example, I've chosen to split the string on each `'1'` char, count and use the length of the resulting array. If the the length > 2, than you know what you need to know.

```
var multipleOnes = ((someNum + '').split('1').length > 2);//returns a bool, true in this case
```

In response to your comment, to make it flexible - writing a simple function will do:

```
function multipleDigit(number, digit, moreThan)
{
    moreThan = (moreThan || 1) + 1;//default more than 1 time, +1 for the length at the end
    digit = (digit !== undefined ? digit : 1).toString();
    return ((someNum + '').split(digit).length > moreThan);
}
multipleDigit(1123, 1);//returns true
multipleDigit(1123, 1, 2);//returns false
multipleDigit(223344,3);//returns 3 -> more than 1 3 in number.
```

Comment: Can I ask, where exactly is the flexibility, because I'm not sure how to implement that.

Comment: @DJDavid98: added an example function that allows you to check for any number, and specify if it has to occur more that n times. Parameter 1 is the number, the second is the digit which you want to check for (defaults to 1), the third parameter is how many times it has to occur (default: more than 1)

Comment: You kind of overdid it with the bigger than part, but thanks, it works perfectly!

Comment: This actually does not exploit the fact that JS is a loosely typed language. You can do primite+string in strongly typed languages like java as well :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Fair point, merely coercing to a string isn't what makes a language loosely typed... I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript's [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method. Essentially, what you'd need to do is first convert the number to a string. Numbers don't have the RegExp methods. After that, match for the number 1 globally and count the results (match returns an array with all matched results).

```
​var number = 1100;
console.log(number.toString().match(/1/g).length);​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function find(num, tofind) {
   var b = parseInt(num, 10);
   var c = parseInt(tofind, 10);
   var a = c.split("");
   var times = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] == b) {
         times++;
      }
   }
   alert(times);
}

find('2', '1122');
```

Comment: Again with the lack of indentation. Please, don't promote this horrid way of writing code!! Add some tabs.

Comment: (If you had, you'd have spotted the `{}` mismatch.)

Comment: thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit for that! ok ok i will try to write code in your way! well, my code works or not?

Comment: No, it had a syntax error. I added indentation, spotted the fault, and fixed it for you. However, I have not validated the semantics of the answer.

Comment: It's just small things, like, alerting random numbers, and passing `1122` as a number, not a string, and thus generating errors.

Comment: Never use `parseInt` without specifying a radix... don't take my word for it, [check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: It does something, but not what I wanted. To start the list of things missing, the function has to return `true` or `false`. +1 for effort.

Comment: well @EliasVanOotegem thanks, BTW FYI the square brackets in syntax shows that following thing is not mandatory! BTW thanks all

Comment: @AspiringAqib: Sure, but read on, in the description section it clearly says _always specify a radix when using parseInt._ (they've even put it in __bold__, so you would be less likely to miss it).

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to a string and iterate over it. Return true once a second digit has been found, for efficiency.

```
function checkDigitRepeat(number, digit) {
    var i, count = 0;

    i = Math.abs(number);
    if(isNaN(i)) {
        throw(TypeError('expected Number for number, got: ' + number));
    }
    number = i.toString();

    i = Math.abs(digit);
    if(isNaN(i)) {
        throw(TypeError('expected Number for digit, got: ' + digit));
    }
    digit = i.toString();

    if(digit > 9) {
        throw(SyntaxError('expected a digit for digit, got a sequence of digits: ' + digit));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < number.length; i += 1) {
        if(number[i] === digit) {
            count += 1;
            if(count >= 2) { return true; }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

In the event that you want to check for a sequence of digits, your solution may lie in using regular expressions.

Comment: This is way too much error checking for the code that I will use it in. Although it does exactly what I wanted. I'll stick with EliasVanOotegem's answer, but thank you!

Comment: Hold on: if I call `checkDigitRepeat('1134',1);` This throws an error: `typeof number` will be `string`. Also: Why wouldn't you allow to check for '123' in numbers like `123123123132`?

Comment: By the criteria in your question, you are looking for a single, repeating digit. '123' is a set of three digits inside a string, right? The type checks are for safety and simplicity's sake. They could be stretched with type conversions, if you wanted.

Comment: Yes, Your function throws an error if I would want to count how many times the sequence of n digits occurs. Why so? Perhaps a `Math.abs()` on the parameters and check if `NaN` would be enough.

Comment: @Chip: Well, I used type coercion, it doesn't add much complexity, and it doesn't require you to write your function calls in try-catch blocks to avoid your script from grinding to a halt. It may be personal, but I don't like JS functions that throw errors because of _"types"_. To me, it doesn't make sense in a loosely typed language

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNum = '0011';

var isMultipleTimes = function(num) {
    return !!num.toString().match(/(\d)\1/g);
}

console.log(isMultipleTimes(myNum));
```

JavaScript [Match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)